# Vectors and Forces

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

A box weighting 294N is sitting on a ramp. If the ramp is inclined at an angle of 25 degrees to the horizontal, and there is a 40N force of friction, calculate  the amount of force that must be applied parallel to the ramp to hold the box in place.

Answer (score 0):

Take component of forces normal and parallel to the incline. Normal Force would cancel any component normal to the incline. The remaining Forces are :

$40N$ opposite to the direction you want to move.

$296\sin25^\circ N$ down the incline.

$F$ you are applying upwards.

As friction is smaller than weight component it can only act upwards.

$F+40N=296\sin25^\circ N$